# From a sentence group all words that start with same alphabet and and sort it according to first character of the word

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

suppose I take a string input from the user , and if will then group all the words in that sentence with respect  to first character of the word and later we have to display the o/p as dictionary , No repetition of words is allowed . 
For example consider i/p string `a="A cat ran after the dog and died due to injury"`

Then o/p should be :

```
{'A': ['A'], 'a': ['after', 'and'], 'c': ['cat'], 'd': ['died', 'dog', 'due'], 'i': ['injury'], 'r': ['ran'], 't': ['the', 'to']}
```

Here is making list according to starting character and all the words starting with that character . 
I have made this program :

```
a="A cat ran after the dog and died due to injury"
b=[]
c={}
b=list(sorted(set(a.split())))
for x in b:
    e=x[0]
    c.setdefault(e,[])
    c[e].append(x)
print (c)
```

Can you suggest me different way to do this . I am not satisfied with this approach of mine . Please provide a algorithmic way .
The language I am using is python3

Comment: What does a/q mean? I'm guessing i/p and o/p are text speak for "input" and "output", but a/q has me stumped. Can you edit the question to use real words please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your code a little but apart from that it's ok

```
from collections import defaultdict
a="A cat ran after the dog and died due to injury"
c=defaultdict(list)

for x in set(a.split()):  # no need to sort unless you create an OrderedDict which you didn't
    c[x[0]].append(x)
print (c)
```

You can replace the loop by

```
any(map(lambda x : c[x[0]].append(x),set(a.split())))
```

Comment: can you do it without any special import , just following algorithms

Comment: your approach was ok in that case: replace `b=list(sorted(set(a.split())))` by `b=set(a.split())`

Answer (score 1):

```
res = {}
for a in "A cat ran after the dog and died due to injury".split():
    k = a[0]
    try: res[k].add(a)
    except KeyError: res[k] = {a}
print(res)
```

Comment: if k not in res: res[k] = set([a]) else res[k].add(a)

Comment: I'd recommend expanding your answer to include some information about how your code solves the problem.

Comment: yes I would also like the expanded answer , or atleast explain your code @vadim .Thanks